# 1 application on multiple domains (multilingual website)

Tags: php, .htaccess, multilingual

Is it possible to have **1 application** (1 source code) of website on **multiple domains**. It is about multilingual website:

```
www.example.com (main website)
www.example.de
www.example.it
```

PHP and MySQL part of website is already working well on subdomains - **1 source code, multiple subdomains** (via **.htaccess**):

```
www.example.com
de.example.com
it.example.com
```

How can it be done on multiple domains, also via **.htaccess** or ?

Comment: It's done by so called virtual hosts - How it works depends on your system/webserver. Also your application must be able to handle it.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. No, you don't really need .htaccess for this. just point all those vhosts at the SAME document root, then have your PHP code check `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` or `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

Comment: ... or set an environment variable (config file path or whatever) in the `<VirtualHost>` directive - then you can do something like `include $_SERVER['CFG_PATH']` - you can change far more than just the language the site is running in through the a bit of jiggery-pokery in the `<VirtualHost>` ;)

Comment: One more question, it is not topic related, but important to my project - about cookies share across multiple domains in this example, is it possible or not ? I know that regular cookies are bound to one domain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to point all your domains to the same folder in your server.

and in your `index.php` or any very first php controller of your application,

or in your `setting.php` where you have to know what domain is in use

you do something like this:

```
$currentDomain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
switch ($currentDomain) {
   case 'www.example.com':
     $database = 'example';
     $tableprefix = 'ex';
     // any preset you need that depend on you domain
     break;
   case 'www.examle.de':
     $database = 'de';
     $tableprefix = 'de';
     // any preset you need that depend on you domain
     break;
   ...
   ...
   default:
     echo 'UNKNOWN DOMAIN '.$currentDomain.'!';
     exit;

}
```

Comment: Thank you all for answers it helped me a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you just configure your server use the same `DocumentRoot` for each of the domains. You cannot use `.htaccess` to configure the `DocumentRoot`.